# Efficiently search a linked list

Tags: c, search, linked-list

I have a sorted linked list, one function takes the root pointer and an Id and searches through the list to delete the item, however this takes linear time.

Is there any way to efficiently search through the linked list without doing it linearly using the fact that its sorted? The assignment hints heavily that their is a better way but I can't think of a way to do it without being terribly inefficient or just using a linear search.

Comment: single linked list or double linked list?  if double you can represent a binary tree and decrease the lookup time to log(n) (albeit the best case for a balanced tree).

Comment: The obvious way to search a sorted array is to binary search it. You can get a small improvement in performance by terminating your search after the id of the next node is greater than (or less, depending on how you sorted) the search key. You can get dramatic performance gains by implementing a [`skip list`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), but that's a pretty big add-on.

Comment: Whose is a better way? Anyway, if you want a more efficient search, you ditch the linked list and use something else. There is no way to search  linked list faster than linearly. Of course you can build a tree or an array or whatever you want in addition to a linked list and search it, but you won't be searching the list then. Actually, you just always ditch the linked list and use something else, regardless. It's almost never the right tool for the job, whatever the job is. But without having **your entire assignment verbatim** this is all pure speculation, not worth the electrons spent on it

Comment: The advantage of using a *sorted* list is that you can stop traversing it once you reach the spot where the item *should have been* (which will save you ~50 % of steps). The disadvantage is that you have to keep the list sorted ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each node in a linked list only contains a pointer to the next node (and optionally the previous node), so without any other constructs the only way to search the list is linearly.

However, since you sort the list, you could build a binary tree in the process.  Then you can use that tree to search the list with a time complexity of `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.